# Stop infinite loop from timeout

Tags: php, file-get-contents

Basically, I have a script that is doing an infinite loop using `file_get_contents`, it's basically just running the function then incrementing the an `$_GET` variable which is passed to the `file_get_contents` url, the problem is obviously it's throwing an error for "Too many redirects", is their a way i can do it on Cron Job or a way of it doing it without error, here's my current code

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$next_id = $id + 1;
$url = "http://www.website.com/profile/$id.json";
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$result = json_decode($json, true);

$headers = get_headers($url);
if($headers[0] !== "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found") {
  $query = mysql_query("query here");
  if($query) {
       echo '<script type="text/javascript">
       <!-- window.location = "import.php?id='.$next_id.'" //-->
       </script>';
  } else {
       echo '<script type="text/javascript">
       <!-- window.location = "import.php?id='.$id.'" //-->
       </script>';
  }
}
```

Is there any other method or more efficient way of doing this ? I've tried using such method as `sleep(5)` before using my redirect but it still seems to keep doing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a pause before the redirect in JavaScript:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
<!-- window.setTimeout("window.location = \"import.php?id='.$next_id.'\"", 5000); //-->
</script>';
```